# Does jetty overwrite custom http status code ?

Tags: rest, jetty, jax-rs, embedded-jetty

I am trying to develop a rest api for my service wherein I set custom http status code depending on authorisation failure. But when I test it out using curl I am receiving 404 instead of 403. I am perplexed as to what might be causing this? Please help.

This is what I see from curl output or swagger UI:

```
root@ubuntu:~# curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/mr/v1/topic/bhakk -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8082 (#0)
> GET /mr/v1/topic/bhakk HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8082
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Mon, 07 May 2018 22:00:10 GMT
< Exception: serviceBlockedException
< Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v1+json
< Content-Length: 83
< Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"error_code":40301,"message":"This service does not have access to the resource."}
```

Here is the code:

```
    public Collection<String> list(@HeaderParam("x-nssvc-serviceid") String serviceID) {
        Date now = new java.util.Date();
        if (! ctx.getSecurityRestrictions().isServiceAllowed(uri, httpHeaders, "Describe", "Cluster", "kafka-cluster"))
          throw Errors.serviceBlockedException(ctx,httpServletResponse);

        List<String> topicsCopy = new ArrayList<String>(topics);
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = topicsCopy.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
          String topic = iterator.next();
          if (! ctx.getSecurityRestrictions().hasAccess (serviceId, "Describe", "Topic", topic)) {
            iterator.remove();
          }
        }

        return topicsCopy;
      }

    public static RestException serviceBlockedException(Context ctx,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Exception","serviceBlockedException");
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(Status.FORBIDDEN.getStatusCode()); <----// here i am setting status code.
        return new RestNotFoundException(SERVICE_ID_BLOCKED_MESSAGE, SERVICE_ID_BLOCKED_ERROR_CODE);
      }
```

Comment: Seems like your `RestNotFoundException` is setting the status to 404 somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka sets the Response 404 status in its `RestNotFoundException`

See: https://github.com/confluentinc/rest-utils/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/confluent/rest/exceptions/RestNotFoundException.java

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks!